# Radius of Curvature

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry

I was asked to show that the expression is constant in a circle :

$\dfrac{\left[1+\left(\dfrac{\operatorname d \!y}{\operatorname d \!x}\right)^2\right]^{\frac 3 2}}{\dfrac{\operatorname d \!^2y}{\operatorname d \!x^2}}$

I found it to be equal to Radius.

Curiosity led me to search more about it on internet. That says that it is radius of curvature of a curve. But I can't find a proof of it.

Please give a proof which I can understand (as simple as possible). Please use a geometric approach. I see that the numerator is cube of $dl$ (differential arc length)

I see that we are lacking a definition of radius of curvature : I want to use the most obvious definition(to me) : Distance of point from centre of curvature at that point where the centre is defined as intersection of two infinitesimally close normals.

Or we could use the physics like $\frac{v^2}{a_\perp}$

Comment: That is the definition, so there is nothing to prove. To understand why it is the definition, think first about a circle. If the radius is small, what can you say about the curvature? If the radius is large?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature and http://en.wikipedia.orgwiki/Radius_of_curvature_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @PhilipHoskins I disagree. You could *define* this as the radius of curvature, but then you would have to prove that a circle of this radius is tangential to the curve at that point. Either way there is plenty to prove, although the proof is quite intuitive.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici edit your link please, that should be **"...org/wiki/...."** as of now, its broken

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(mathematics)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't get that it being equal to $\frac{ds}{d\theta}$

Comment: In the sense of the curve of radius $r$, we get from the definition of radian measure that $\Delta s = r\Delta \theta$. Hence, $ds/d\theta =r$

Comment: @L__ I meant that expression being equal to this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a curve, $ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$.

Also, $\tan \theta=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

So, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{ds}{d\theta}&=&\frac{ds}{dx}.\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{\frac{ds}{dx}}{\frac{d\theta}{dx}}\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}}{\frac{d\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}}
\\&=&\frac{\left[1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right]^{3/2}}{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: $\tan\theta = dy/dx$...Got you! Thanks.

Comment: To generalize the concept of the radius of curvature to all curves, suppose we don't know that curves can be approximated as infinitesimal circular arcs. We know that $\frac{ds}{d\theta}=r$ for a circular arc, and the formula above, which is general, can be accepted as the radius yielded by the *closest approximation* of an infinitesimal arc of any curve as circular( and we know this works as since ds and $d\theta$ are infinitesimally small, it would give a near-perfect approximation, which means we *can* consider the arc circular)...

Comment: (contd.) which is also what the definition of the radius of curvature is. Hopefully that doesn't sound like nonsense; it cleared up something for me. Genius answer!

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to start with curvature. Given a curve
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto {\bf z}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\qquad(a<t<b)$$
the vector $\dot{\bf z}(t)=\bigl(\dot x(t),\dot y(t)\bigr)$ points for each $t$ in the direction of the forward tangent vector at ${\bf z}(t)$. Curvature is about the speed by which this tangent vector turns. As this is a purely geometric concept time $t$ should not enter into the definition. This means that we have to measure this speed with respect to arc length $s$.

The polar angle of the tangent vector is given by $\theta(t)=\arg\bigl(\dot {\bf z}(t)\bigr)$. It follows by the chain rule that
$$\dot\theta(t)=\nabla\arg\bigl(\dot{\bf z}(t)\bigr)\cdot\ddot{\bf z}(t)\ .$$
As $\nabla\arg(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2},{x\over x^2+y^2}\right)$ we obtain
$$\dot\theta(t)=\left({-\dot y\over \dot x^2+\dot y^2},{\dot x\over \dot x^2+\dot y^2}\right)\cdot\bigl(\ddot x(t),\ddot y(t)\bigr)={\dot x \ddot y-\dot y\ddot x\over \dot x^2+\dot y^2}\ .$$
Now we need ${d\theta\over ds}$ instead of ${d\theta\over dt}$. Since $\dot s=\sqrt{ \dot x^2+\dot y^2}$ applying the chain rule again gives
$$\kappa={d\theta\over ds}={\dot\theta\over\dot s}={\dot x \ddot y-\dot y\ddot x\over \left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2\right)^{3/2}}\ .\tag{1}$$
Apply formula $(1)$ to the case of a graph $x\mapsto\bigl(x, y(x)\bigr)$ (here $x$ is the parameter) and take the reciprocal to obtain the radius of curvature.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of curvature of a curve at a point is the radius of the circle that best approximates the curve at that point.

So first, let us find the differential equation representing the family of circles with a particular radius $r_0$.
The equation of a circle is
$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r_0^2$$
Differentiating two times and finding the expressions for h and k in terms of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ gives

$$y-k = -\left[\cfrac{1+ \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{2}}{\frac{d^2y
}{dx^2}}\right]$$
$$x-h = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\left[\cfrac{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}}{\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)}\right]$$

and
$$\left[\cfrac{\left[1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right]^{3/2}}{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}\right] = r_0$$

Let $f(x)$ be a general function
a general point on its graph would be $(t, f(t))$

Now, consider all the circles passing through $(t,f(t))$.
If we want to approximate the function in the neighbourhood of that point with a circle,
it would be good if as many of the derivatives as possible of the function at that point equal the derivatives of the circle at the same point.
[Similar to how the polynomial approximation (i.e. Taylor series) in general increases in accuracy with greater number of terms]

But we see that if we fix the values:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = f'(t)$ and
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = f''(t)$,
it fixes both the centre of the circle as well as the radius.

Hence we cannot expect any further derivatives (i.e. $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ etc) to be equal for the function and the circle, and this is the best possible approximation of the curve as a circle, at that point.
And the radius of this circle would be the radius of curvature of the graph at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I derived something, and it may be exactly what you were (or maybe still are) looking for. I show every step, so the math is a bit stretched (4 pages), but I feel it is better to be simpler than shorter. It's based on the definition you stated in your question.

[An alternative derivation of radius of curvature (2D functions). How valid is it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636881/an-alternative-derivation-of-radius-of-curvature-2d-functions-how-valid-is-it)