# An alternative derivation of radius of curvature (2D functions). How valid is it?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, curvature

I was wondering how radius of curvature was derived, and this is what I came up with. It turned out to be longer than expected. Then I looked at how it compares with other (presumably more mathematically accurate) derivations on the Internet. Everywhere I looked had the same approach, where they first looked at curvature by finding the rate of change of the angle between the tangent at the point of interest and the $x$-axis, with respect to arc length, and then getting to the radius of curvature. What I've done seems more of a direct approach to me, maybe more geometric as well.

What I started with:

[image: visual representation and starting equation]

What I finished with:

$$R = \left | \frac{(1+f'(a)^2))^{\frac{3}{2}}}{f''(a)} \right |$$

Before getting to that I made these statements:

$$\left (  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h)=f(a)\right )$$

and
\begin{align*}
\text{By definition:}\qquad
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} &= f'(a), \\
\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{h} &= f''(a).
\end{align*}

I'm not sure about the statement in the brackets on the fourth page. It feels right, but I'm not sure. That statement also seems like it's contradicting the "By definition..." statement on the third page? Any thoughts on this, or on the derivation in general?

(Full derivation at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LamLT1ywM1M1NzOHVUQnFvd2M/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-0wvgtszqdJPteKUxY3Fakg)

Update: Changed link, also by "It turned out to be longer than expected" I mean 4 pages long...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Could you please synthesize the contents of the links so that your question is self-contained? As is, I'm not going to click of a google doc, and I expect many people here are similarly disinclined. Security risks aside, this is a Q&A site that aims to be useful in the long term, and links tend to break with time. Thanks. :)

Comment: Okay, I have made it more self contained now, thanks for the advice. I still needed to add a link to an image though. I am not yet allowed to post images.

Comment: (+1) Thank you. I took the liberty of adding the image and tweaking two of the displayed equations.

Comment: Your idea and formula are correct, but (unfortunately) well-known, see, e.g., [curvature of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph). (The curvature is the reciprocal of the radius of curvature.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congrats, I actually took the time to read it all, I have been looking for a radious of curvature derivation that does not involve the abstract formulation done in calculus, or the crappy infinitesimal aproximations done in physics or mechanics. It is fairly correct (although you could have made much shorter if taken the limit much before, remember you can put a limit inside a continous function like the abs value or well... everything you had here)...